# How to run multiple dependent sql statements in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sqlalchemy, subquery

### Problem

I have a bunch of dependent SQL statements that I would like to run in the same context in sqlalchemy, but I cannot make it work.

### Running All at Once

```
values = ', '.join(f"('{id}')" for id in obligor_ids)
q = f"""
    USE {database};
    DECLARE @ObligorIDs AS {schema}.ObligorIDListType;
    INSERT INTO @ObligorIDs (ID) VALUES {values};
    SELECT * FROM {schema}.GetLUsByObligorID(@ObligorIDs);
"""
engine.execute(q)
```

Failes with error message "This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically" because multiple batches cannot be run in one query. I have also tried wrapping the string in "text" as suggested multiple places, but with the same result. When I run the EXACT same query in SQL Management Studio it works like a charm.

### Running batches one-by-one in a Session

```
# Switching to sql function database
q1 = f"USE {database};"

# Declaring input

q2 = f"DECLARE @ObligorIDs AS {schema}.ObligorIDListType;"
q3 = f"INSERT INTO @ObligorIDs (ID) VALUES {values};"

# Declaring output
q4 = f"SELECT * FROM {schema}.GetLUsByObligorID(@ObligorIDs);"

# Running sql function
with Session(engine) as session:
    session.execute(q1)
    session.execute(q2)
    session.execute(q3)
    result = session.execute(q4).fetchall()
    session.commit()
```

This fails because session.execute(q4) cannot access @ObligorIDs.

Comment: Try slapping: `SET NOCOUNT ON;` as the first statement in your batch mayhaps

Comment: Just tried, and it gives the exact same error.

Comment: you mean, even before the USE database thing? Did you try it with text() too?

Comment: Yes, same error "ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically."

Comment: Try executing the USE statement separately, then the remaining statements as a single code block beginning with  `SET NOCOUNT ON;`, all on the same connection.

Comment: It turned out you were right @siggemannen, thanks :)

Comment: Great, time to raise another beer glass for `SET NOCOUNT ON`

Comment: It should probably be a default setting :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the following code works. But I am not sure why.

```
# Switching to sql function database
q1 = f"SET NOCOUNT ON;USE {database};"
with Session(engine) as session:
    session.execute(q1)
    session.commit()

# Insert obligor IDs into the input table
q2 = f"""
    DECLARE @ObligorIDList AS {schema}.ObligorIDListType;
    INSERT INTO @ObligorIDList (ID) VALUES {', '.join(f"('{id}')" for id in obligor_ids)};
    SELECT * FROM {schema}.GetLUsByObligorID(@ObligorIDList);
"""

# Running query
pd.read_sql_query(con=engine, sql=text(q2))
```

### NOTE:

It turns out "SET NOCOUNT ON" was the needed trick!

Comment: Putting `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the beginning of q2 is still recommended. It's a good habit to get into.